# On raspberry i'm getting this error:picamera.exc.PiCameraNotRecording: There is no recording in progress on port 1

Tags: python-3.x, camera, raspberry-pi3

On raspberry pi 3, with Raspberry camera v2 and using python 3.4.2,
sometimes, totally random, i get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1189, in stop_recording
    encoder = self._encoders[splitter_port]
KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 496, in fill
    self.parent._fire_events()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 315, in _fire_events
    self._fire_deactivated()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 294, in _fire_deactivated
    self.when_deactivated()
  File "/home/pi/Programmi/Camera+sensoreX/cam_sens2.py", line 48, in stop_video
    camera.stop_recording()                         #stoppiamo la registrazione
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1193, in stop_recording
    'port %d' % splitter_port)
picamera.exc.PiCameraNotRecording: There is no recording in progress on port 1
```

But most of the time the program works.
How to solve this?
The Program:

```
import os                                           #Importo modulo os per gestione dei percorsi dei file e cartelle
import cayenne.client                               #importo modulo cayenne.client per poter mandare dati a cayenne e quindi attivare le trigger e notifiche.
import datetime as date                             #Importo modulo datetime per la gestione del tempo abbreviandolo come "date"
import RPi.GPIO as gpio                             #Importo modulo GPIO per la gestione dei pin del gpio del raspberry abbreviandolo come "gpio"
#Se non si desidera utilizzare il nome della libreria tutte le volte che si richiama una funzione, è possibile importare anche i nomi delle funzioni direttamente: from [modulo] import [nome_funzione]
from picamera import PiCamera                       #Importo la funzione PiCamera dal modulo picamera
from time import sleep                              #Importo la funzione "sleep" dal modulo time
from gpiozero import MotionSensor                   #Importo la funzione MotionSensor dal modulo gpiozero
gpio.setwarnings(False)                         #Disabilito i messaggi di avvertimento del modulo GPIO
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)                          #Numerazione dei pin della GPIO di tipo BCM = numerazione pin secondo ai numeri dei pin SoC Broadcom, quindi usando i numeri dei pin "GPIO"
sensore = 4                                     #il sensore di movimento sarà collegato al pin 7 della GPIO (4 BCM)
gpio.setup(sensore, gpio.IN)                    #pin 7 impostato come input

camera = PiCamera()                                  #help?                   
sensor = MotionSensor(4)                             #help?
#camera.hflip = True                                 #camera ad effetto specchio (flip orizzontale)
camera.resolution = (1280, 720)                      #impostiamo la risoluzione della registrazione, in HD 1280x720p (larghezza, altezza)
destinazione = '/home/pi/Registrazioni'              #path (percorso) dove andremo a salvare i file di registrazione

cont_iniz = 3                      #valore inizale del contatore (3 secondi), necessario per l'inizializzazione del sensore 
durata_registrazione = 15          #secondi di registrazione
durata_tot = 0                     #variabile usata tenere conto della durata della registrazione eseguita        

#variabili globali, per utilizzare i valori letti all'interno di una funzione (conf_routine) nel main
tempo_uscita_letto = 0             
tempo_entrata_letto = 0             #tempo per entrare in casa e chiudere il programma

#Credenziali di autenticazione di Cayenne, possono essere ottenuti dalla dashboard di Cayenne.
MQTT_USERNAME  = "private_info"
MQTT_PASSWORD  = "private_info"
MQTT_CLIENT_ID = "private_info"

#inizializzazione della connessione con Cayenne MyDevices
client = cayenne.client.CayenneMQTTClient()
client.begin(MQTT_USERNAME, MQTT_PASSWORD, MQTT_CLIENT_ID)

#definiamo la funzione countdown che utilizziamo per impostare un tempo di registrazione in secondi e decrementarlo fino a 0, ma se nel frattempo il sensore rileva un altro movimento, il tempo viene reimpostato al valore inziale 
def countdown(contatore):
    global durata_tot                                   #importiamo la variabile globale durata_tot
    notifica_cayenne()                                  #notifichiamo via sms e/o e-mail che è stato rilevato un movimento
    while (contatore >= 0):                             #finché il valore del contatore (passato attraverso la variabile durata_registrazione) è maggiore o uguale a zero
        print (contatore)                               #output a video del valore del contatore
        durata_tot += 1                                 #incrementiamo il valore della durata totale, dato che ogni ciclo del while corrisponde a 1 secondo
        contatore -= 1                                  #decrementiamo il contatore 
        if gpio.input(sensore):                         #se riceviamo un input dal sensore sulla GPIO (quindi il sensore rileva un movimento)...
           contatore = durata_registrazione                 #il contatore viene resettato al valore iniziale (quindi al valore della variabile durata_registrazione)
        sleep(1)                                        #interrompiamo l'esecuzione del programma per un secondo

#definiamo la funzione registra_video che utilizziamo, a grandi linee, per iniziare la registrazione del video, darci un nome , definire la durata e cartella di destinazione 
def registra_video():
    #generariamo il nome univoco del video basato sull'ora e data attuale e creiamo un "percorso completo" aggiungendo il percorso (variabile destinazione) della cartella in cui vogliamo salvare il video
    nome_file = os.path.join(destinazione, date.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M.%S.h264")) 
    #iniziamo l'anteprima della registrazione in corso, impostiamo che non la vogliamo a schermo intero e quindi impostiamo le coordinate della finestra (x, y, larghezza, altezza)
    camera.start_preview(fullscreen=False, window =(100, 200, 640, 480))
    #iniziamo la registrazione specificando il nome del file (variabile nome_file) generato precedentemente
    camera.start_recording(nome_file)
    print ("Registrazione Iniziata")                #output a video per notificarci che la registrazione è iniziata
    countdown(durata_registrazione)                 #chiamiamo la funzione countdown, specificando la durata della registrazione

#definiamo la funzione stop_video, che stopperà il video una volta che il conto alla rovescia sarà finito
def stop_video():
        global durata_tot, tempo_uscita_letto, tempo_entrata_letto          #importiamo variabili globali necessarie
        camera.stop_recording()                         #stoppiamo la registrazione
        camera.stop_preview()                           #chiudiamo l'anteprima
        durata_tot2 = float(durata_tot) + float(tempo_entrata_letto) #calcolo della durata della registrazione effettiva
        print ("Registrazione Stoppata. Filmato di {} secondi".format(durata_tot2))      #output a video per notificarci che la registrazione è finita, mostrandoci la durata in secondi
        #azzeriamo il valori che tengono conto della durata totale delle singole registrazioni, per conteggiare per la prossima registrazione
        durata_tot = 0                                  
        durata_tot2 = 0                                 
        print("Aspettando movimenti...")                #output a video per notificarci che il sistema è in attesa di movimenti  

#definiamo la funzione conf_routine, che ci permette di impostare i tempi di uscita ed entrata in casa e salvarli in un file 
def conf_routine():
    global tempo_uscita_letto, tempo_entrata_letto               #importiamo la variabili globali dichiarate tempo_uscita_letto e tempo_entrata_letto 
    nomefile = "conf.txt"                   #nome predefinito del file di configurazione
    if os.path.isfile(nomefile) == False:   #se il file contenente la configurazione non esiste...
        print ("ATTENZIONE! Non è stato trovato alcun file di configurazione, verrà creato...\n") #notifica all'utente che non è presente il file di configurazione
        file = open (nomefile,"w")                  #creiamo il file (in scrittura)
        file.close()                                #chiudiamo il file

    if os.stat(nomefile).st_size == False:     #se il file esiste ma è vuoto (quindi non è stata effettuata la configurazione)...
        file = open (nomefile,"a")                  #apriamo il file in append mode
        tempo_uscita = input("Inserisci il tempo (in secondi) che impieghi solitamente ad uscire dall'abitazione una volta avviato il programma: ") #inseriamo il tempo che impieghiamo solitamente per uscire di casa
        file.write(tempo_uscita + "\n")             #scriviamo nella prima riga del file il tempo che impieghiamo ad uscire di casa
        tempo_entrata = input("\nInserisci il tempo (in secondi) che impieghi solitamente ad entrare nell'abitazione una volta avviato il programma: ")
        file.write(tempo_entrata)                   #scriviamo nella seconda riga del file il tempo che impieghiamo ad entrare in casa
        print("\nATTENZIONE! Se vorrai cambiare i tempi impostati, dovrai aprire il file cambiare manualmente i secondi oppure, cancellare il file e riavviare il programma\n") #messaggio di avviso
        file.close()                                #chiudiamo il file

    file = open (nomefile, "r")                 #apriamo il file in sola lettura
    riga = file.readlines()                     #leggiamo ogni riga del file e le mettiamo nella variabile riga
    tempo_uscita_letto = riga[0]                #mettiamo nella variabile globale tempo_uscita_letto il valore letto dalla prima riga del file
    tempo_entrata_letto = riga[1]               #mettiamo nella variabile globale tempo_entrata_letto il valore letto dalla seconda riga del file
    file.close()                                #chiudiamo il file
    print ("\nTempo per uscire: {} secondi\n".format(float(tempo_uscita_letto)))     #output a video del valore letto
    print ("Tempo per entrare: {} secondi\n".format(float(tempo_entrata_letto)))     #output a video del valore letto



#definiamo la funzione che permette a cayenne di mandarci una notifica via mail e/o messaggio
#impostiamo un "trigger" dal sito di cayenne, che scatta quando il valore sul canale 2 diventa 1. Il trigger, una volta scattato, manda la notifica.
#mandiamo 0 e poi 1 perché il trigger perché scatta nel passaggio del dato da 0 a 1; quindi, se mandassimo solo 1, il trigger non scatterebbe mai.
def notifica_cayenne():
    sleep (float(tempo_entrata_letto))          #ritardo necessario per disattivare il sistema dopo l'entrata in casa
    client.virtualWrite(2, 0)                   #mandiamo un dato digitale (0) a cayenne, sul canale 2 [canale, valore]
    client.virtualWrite(2, 1)                   #mandiamo un dato digitale (1) a cayenne, sul canale 2 [canale, valore]

############################################# main #############################################
def main():
    global cont_iniz                                    #importiamo la variabile globale dichiarata cont_iniz
    print("Inizializzo il sensore, attendere {} secondi".format(cont_iniz))     #output a video per notificarci che inizialmente dobbiamo attendere 3 secondi per permettere al sensore di inizializzarsi
    #semplice conto alla rovesca in base al valore di cont_iniz || aspettiamo 3 secondi, necessari per inizializzare il sensore.
    while (cont_iniz >= 0):                                                 
        print (cont_iniz)
        cont_iniz -= 1
        sleep(1)
    conf_routine()                                      #esecuzione delle routine di configurazione, dove eventualmente viene creato il file e ci vengono salvati (e poi letti) il tempo di entrata ed uscita
    sleep (float(tempo_uscita_letto))                   #aspettiamo il tempo impostato prima di continuare ad eseguire il programma, dandoci tempo per uscire di casa, evitando di essere riconosciuti come intrusi
    print("Aspettando movimenti...")                    #output a video per notificarci che il sistema è in attesa di movimenti
    while True:                                         #ciclo infinito, il sistema aspetta input dal sensore, in base ad essi fa partire le funzioni di inizio o interruzione della registrazione
        client.loop()                                       #connessione continua con Cayenne.
        sensor.when_motion = registra_video                 #se viene rilevato dal sensore un movimento, parte? la funzione che inizia la registrazione del video (registra_video)
        sensor.when_no_motion = stop_video                  #se non viene rilevato dal sensore nessun movimento, parte? la funzione che stoppa la registrazione del video (stop_video)

if __name__ == "__main__":                              #main
    main()
```

Thanks in advance.

P.s: if you want to help me comment the instruction, obviously in English, I would appreciate it. I mean the instruction followed by: #help?